# Can information be brought from windows device manager using java program?

Tags: java

I want to bring the information stored in device manager since there is no way to detect hardwares directly using java.Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Not in pure Java.  You'll need to use JNI and some Windows C/C++ to get access to that level of info.  If that's too much work, you could make use of something like [xFunction](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/xfunction.html).